# Div inside another div does not have the same height

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside another div and I wonder why the inner div's height isn't the same as its parent? I set the height of the parent div to 40px, but the child div does not seem to stretch to this height. Am I wrong about the height of divs?

*Making it simple*

```
<div id="first" style="height:40px"><div id="second"></div></div>
```

Comment: What kind of display attribute do your divs have ? What browser are you checking in ? Are you using a CSS reset ?

Comment: All other factors aside, a block element will only grow ass tall as the content within it - not as tall as it's parent element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A div will only be as tall as the content within it (see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTP2V/)). To extend a child div to the height of its parent, add `height: 100%` to the child.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#first {
    height: 40px;
}

#second {
    height: 100%;;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6RsrX/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that child div element is the same height as the parent element you should use min-height.

```
<style type="text/css">
div.main
{
    width:auto;
    height:500px;
}

div.content
{ 
    width: 100%;
    min-height:90%;
    border:2px solid FF0000;
}

</style>
```

in the body

```
<div class="main">
<div class="content">
<stuff here>
</div>
</div>
```

The attribute height alone is not always recognized in IE which is why I like to use min-height.